# Macbook Air with 20.10 connects to WLAN but no internet with router tplink

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, macbook

Complete noob here. My macbook air is from 2015. When using my isp modem no problem, but with a tplink TL-WR841HP it connects to the wlan but has no internet.

All other devices work fine with the new wlan. I have tried dhcp on and off, different dns servers and blocking ipv6, but I dont really know much else.

```
miguelito@MacBookAir:~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Bucle local)
        RX packets 893  bytes 76496 (76.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 893  bytes 76496 (76.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2806:260:4410:dd9:f240:eca:4a83:d60f  prefixlen 64
scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::6ef5:ece6:b870:7077  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2806:260:4410:dd9::2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2806:260:4410:dd9:bc44:510c:ac77:88c0  prefixlen 64
scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether d0:81:7a:b9:ee:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9266  bytes 9747379 (9.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 246
        TX packets 4197  bytes 986235 (986.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the channel width from auto to 40Mhz. I seems to work ok now.

So probably had nothing to do with the device or the os.